# inline block shrinking images

Tags: responsive-design, css

I'm trying to get my in-line blocks to shrink instead of wrapping. The images are arranged like this:

> AAA  BBB
>
> CCCCCC

as the window gets to be the width of C I want all of the images to shrink together. Right now what I'm getting is C shrinks and B wraps under A. If I set whitespace:nowrap in the parent DIV A and B don't wrap, but don't shrink either. Here's My Code:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="small_pic"><img a></div>
<div class="small_pic"><img b></div>
<div class="large_pic"><img c></div>
</div>

#container {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width: 486px;
max-width:100%;
}
.small_pic {
width:220px;
max-width:100%;
display:inline-block;
height:auto;
}
.large_pic {

width:480px;
max-width:100%;
display:inline-block;
height:auto;
}
```

THANKS!

Comment: can you jsfiddle it with actual images to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go with relative widths for .small_pic instead of absolute - change 220px to 45% and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through your code. One thing you have missed is width of elements that should be in em's or %'s instead of px's.
By the way i was experimenting with your code

```
<div id="container">
<div class="small_pic">
  <img src="My_Bad_by_PhunkyVenom.jpg" class="firstImg">
  <img src="My_Bad_by_PhunkyVenom.jpg" class="secondImg">
</div>
<div class="large_pic"><img src="My_Bad_by_PhunkyVenom.jpg"></div>
</div>


#container {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width: 50%;
/*max-width:100%;
*/}
.small_pic {
/*width:220px;*/        // You've used pixels
max-width:100%;
display:inline-block;
height:auto;
clear:both;
}
.firstImg,.secondImg{width:50%;float:left;}
.large_pic img{
/*width:480px;*/        //You've used pixels.
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
min-height:100px;
height: 30%;
}
```

You can use em's (eg: 300px ~ 18.75px). You don't have to use white-space, just use float-clear. Hope you get it.